# How to Add Content Type to library from Content Type hub using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, content-type, power-automate, content-type-hub

I have developed a solution using Power Automate to provision a site collection from a SharePoint List. When a user attempts to add an item to the list, Power Automate is triggered, resulting in the creation of a new site collection.

Now, I have a set of pre-existing content types in the Content Type hub that I intend to include in this new site collection using the Power Automate API. However, I consistently encountered an error message during this process.

here is my action for adding content type from the flow:

[image]

Referring to the discussion found in this thread: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Adding-a-Content-Type-to-a-document-library-using-Send-HTTP/td-p/946420

It appears that adding a content type using the SharePoint API may not be possible. However, there is an alternative option available using the `$batch` feature in the v2.1 API, specifically the `addCopyFromContentTypeHub` method. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find a definitive solution for this issue. I'm wondering if anyone has successfully resolved this problem in the past.

Below is the new action I attempted to use with `$batch`, but it did not yield the desired results.

[image]